# No Route to Host Exception - Attempting to Remote Connect to Postgresql Database

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I'm currently trying to remotely connect to a Postgresql through a Java program. I've got the JDBC Driver working but when I try to connect to the database, the connection fails and I get a `java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)` error.

So far I've made the following attempts to fix things:

1. On the server containing the postgresql database, I made changed pg_hba.conf to include the IP address of the device trying to connect:

   `# IPv4 local connections:
   host     all      all      127.0.0.1/32          trust
   host     all      all      192.168.25.170/32     trust`
2. I also updated postgresql.conf so that `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'` was changed to `#listen_addresses = '*'`
   **Edit** changed to `listen_addresses = '*'` based on suggestion

I've rebooted the computer multiple times but still get the error. One thing I've noticed is that when I perform `sudo netstat -nlp | grep postgres` I get:

```
`tcp     0     0 0.0.0.0:5433     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN     1309/postgres
 tcp6    0     0 :::5433          :::*          LISTEN     1309/postgres
 unix  2     [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20873     1309/postgres     /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5433`
```

This confuses me because I know the default port for postgres is supposed to 5432, and I'm curious if because this isn't the default port that I'm having the issue?

**Edit**
Note that I've ran the code locally to access the database and locally it works perfectly. When I edit the code to be remote access is when the error occurs. Here is the java code:

```
public class HdfsTransferToDatabase {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    //SQLData sql = new SQLData();

    System.out.println("---------- PostgreSQL JDBC Connection Testing ----------");

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? " 
                        + "Include it in your library path.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("---------- PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered ----------");

    Connection connection = connect();

    if(connection != null) {
        System.out.println("---------- Connection Successful for PostgreSQL ----------");
        //sql.viewTable(connection);
    } else {
        System.out.println("---------- Connection Failed for PostgreSQL ----------");
    }
}

private static Connection connect() {
    //Connection string
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.25.179:5433/gisdb";
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                url, "testuser", "testpassword");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return conn;
}

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the port is the issue, but you can always change the port in postgresql.conf with `port = 5432`. The entry is usually located directly below the `listen_address' entry.

Comment: The `java.net.NoRouteToHostException` is a hint that the server machine is actually not reachable from your client computer. If your client could reach the server but PostgreSQL was not listening, you'd get a `java.net.ConnectException` (Connection refused) exception.

Comment: But I can ping the ip address and the ping works

Comment: Have you tried to telnet to the PostgreSQL port from your client machine?

Comment: If I try to us port 5433 it says `No route to host` if I telnet with port 5432 I get `Connection refused`

Comment: So there's something (a firewall?) blocking communication to port 5433. I'd recommend to let your PostgreSQL server run on the standard port 5432 and try again.

Comment: I already checked firewalls, they're off on both machines. I made the update to postgresql.conf for the port to be 5432 however, when I use `netstat` it still says that postgre is using port 5433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my personal case, I think something went wrong in the installation of my Postgres. Despite `pg_hba.conf` being updated for postgres to use port 5432, it was not actually using this port and port 5433 wasn't allowing me to access anything.

I removed my Postgres through this process:

`yum remove postgres\*
mv /var/lib/pgsql /var/lib/old.pgsql`

Then I used these [instructions](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/install-postgresql-on-centos-7/) to reinstall postgres, except I used the following yum repository to install 9.5.3 instead of 9.4.

`http://yum.postgresql.org/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-3.noarch.rpm`

Note that I use Centos 7 x64.

I made the changes to `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` as I did before, making sure I take the `#` out from `postgresql.conf` and now everything is working well!

Answer (score 0):

What attracts my attention is your change to postgresql.conf. If you really changed the line to `#listen_addresses = '*'`, this might be the problem. The `#` at the start of the line marks the line as comment, so it has no effect, and the listen address defaults to `localhost`.

So try removing the `#` in front of `listen_address` in postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Comment: I removed the `#` and rebooted the system but it still won't remotely connect.